# iOS7 reacts differently to this NSMutableCharacterSet algorithm

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have this basic text-checking code that has worked fine up until iOS 7:

```
   NSMutableCharacterSet*testchars=[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
  [testchars addCharactersInString:@".-"];

  BOOL didFindBadCharacters = ([userInput rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[testchars invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound);
```

The simple idea here is to check the user's input which is `userInput` and find a BOOL that is `true` if any of the characters the user entered are *not* alphanumeric or contain a dot or dash. That is, those entries are fine, but a space, or a symbol, are not fine.

Until iOS 7, this worked. I don't understand why this would be different with iOS 7, but now if the user enters a dot or a dash, the BOOL returns as `true` when I've logged to make sure there is no other character, such as a space, triggering the error instead.

Why would this fail on iOS 7? Seems like basic language features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why would this fail on iOS 7?

My only guess as to why this would be different in iOS 7 is that they have fixed a bug: prior to iOS 7, cocoa used to return a mutable character set for the built-in character sets.

The documentation does not say that the `NSCharacterSet` returned from `alphanumericCharacterSet` should be mutable, so the assignment on the first line is invalid, even though the compiler does not complain.

This should fix the problem:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet*testchars = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: they should add a compiler warning about assigning immutable to mutable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the first line of your code does what you think it does. It probably assigns  a `NSCharacterSet` object to `testchars` (that is, a non-mutable set). As a result, the 2nd line probably does nothing. Try initing your `testchars` as a proper `NSMutableCharacterSet`, I bet your code would work then.

As @dasblinkenlight correctly suggests, this should do the trick:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *testchars = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
```